# Table has no column named error

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i'm using these codes but I am getting error as "table book info has no column named pdate" 
Database class 's method

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {       
// TODO Auto-generated method stub      
String CREATE_BOOK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE bookinfo ( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                "title TEXT, "+
                "author TEXT,"+
                 "pdate TEXT)";         
     db.execSQL(CREATE_BOOK_TABLE);     
}
```

Comment: If you recently added the column, uninstall the app so your `CREATE TABLE` is run again.

Comment: if you ecently added the column, use onupgrade method

Comment: Just reinstall your app and you'll see the Magic

Comment: @SimplePlan Reinstalling doesn't remove app data such as databases. Uninstalling does.

Comment: @laalto you are right.

Comment: @Tamer çözümü buldunmu abi? yeniden **drop** **create** et yada onupgrade e **alter** script i ekleyebilirsin aşağıda cevap verdim

Answer (score 1):

Here is another thing that you can try and see if it works.

Did you add `pdate` field after running your app at least once with a `Create` query having only `id`, `title`, `author` fields? If yes, then you must increment the database version number and run the app again.

Or as per the comment by **@laalto**, you must uninstall the app and install again. This is a normal thing during development :)

The database is never created again until you increment the database version even if you change the create queries.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String CREATE_BOOK_TABLE = "book";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + CREATE_BOOK_TABLE + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                " title TEXT,  "+
                " author TEXT, "+
                " pdate TEXT) ");  

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
       //if you change somethin you modify this
    }
}
```

Comment: @EG i dont think so error is generate for the Space. go to this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230499/table-has-no-column-named-error-sqlite?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230499/table-has-no-column-named-error-sqlite?rq=1)

Comment: Çok teşekkür ederim ,sorunu çözdüm(Thanks for Everyone,i solved problem)

Comment: peki puan verilmeyi hakettim mi :)